# PostgresSQL backup particular schema

Tags: database, postgresql, kubernetes, backup

Any know how to Backup and Restore specific schame  in PostgreSQL.
I'm experiencing difficulties backing up and restoring a specific schema in PostgreSQL. I've attempted multiple methods, but I'm encountering errors.

Method 1

Backup:

```
pg_dump -Fd -j 4 -v -h db-cluster-ha.postgresql.svc.cluster.local -n 'abc' -U abc -d abc -f abc
```

Restore:

```bash
pg_restore -Fd -j 4 -v -U abc_bk -h db-cluster-ha.postgresql.svc.cluster.local -d abc abc
```

**Note:**
I have created a user with permission for the particular schema to address the error, but it did not resolve the issue.

1. CREATE USER abc_bk WITH PASSWORD 'abc_bk'; GRANT USAGE,
2. CREATE ON SCHEMA 'abc' TO abc_bk; GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON ALL
3. TABLES IN SCHEMA 'abc' TO abc_bk;

I also attempted to set the default schema at the database level, but it did not work.

ALTER DATABASE abc SET search_path TO "abc";```

Errors:

- During restore: `pg_restore: error: could not execute query: ERROR: relation "abc.document" does not exist.`

Method 2:
Restore using COPY data:

```bash
pg_restore -U abc -h db-cluster-ha.postgresql.svc.cluster.local -d abc -n 'abc'abc.sql
```

Error:

- During restore: `ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'Subject"`

Method 3:
Backup using inserts option:

```
pg_dump --inserts -j 4 -v -h db-cluster-ha.postgresql.svc.cluster.local -n 'abc' -U abc -d abc -f inserts_abc.sql
```

Error:

- During backup: `ERROR: unterminated quoted string at or near "'Subject"`

Comment: 1) Per docs [pg_dump](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-pgdump.html): *When -n is specified, pg_dump makes no attempt to dump any other database objects that the selected schema(s) might depend upon. Therefore, there is no guarantee that the results of a specific-schema dump can be successfully restored by themselves into a clean database.*.  2) This `'314e'` does not need to be quoted 3) Try without `-j 4`.

Comment: Was the error you reported with pg_restore the only error which occurred, or did you just report the  last-occurring error?

Comment: i have reported last error (Specific error)

Comment: i have tired multiple option didn't work , 1) tried without -j 4 2) without -n {Schema}

Comment: You have to show us the *first* error you get during the restore.